# Why is @JoinColumn in the parent side but produced column is in the child?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I got confusion about entities  relation here:

```
class Country{
        @Id
        @Column(name="conId")
        private int id;         
    @Column(name="name")    
        private String name;
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)   @JoinColumn(name="countryId")   
        private Set<a_1_State_lazy> states;
            }
```

and

```
class State{
@Id         
@Column(name = "stateId")       
private int id;         
@Column(name = "name")  
private String name;    
        @Column(name="countyId")        
private int countryId;

    }
```

When your persist these entities. It produces this tables

`Country`:

- conId
- name

`State`:

-stateId

-name

-countryId

My confusion here is that 
`Country` is the parent entity and `State` is the child entity (where there is a countryId linked to the parent entity's ID).

This

```
class Country{
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
    private int id;          
   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)     
   @JoinColumn(name="countryId")
   private Set<a_1_State_lazy> states;
    }
```

Should (from my limited understanding) be outputing :

`Country`:
- conId
- name
- stateId

instead it constructs a table contains:

`Country`:

- conId
- name

so this "stateId" is missing. And it creates "conId" instead in the `State` table that is:

`State`:

-stateId

-name

- countryId

Why didn't this `Contry` table contain "stateId"? Instead it create "countryId" in the `State` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the Schema generated from your Entities satisfies the First normal form of databases: All columns have to contain atomic values ([First normal form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)).

Therefore, instead of a `states` column containing all the IDs of every State contained in the Country, the information has been moved to the "many" side of the "one to many" relationship.